# App Studio does not support manifest version 1.5

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-appstudio

The App Studio import function is out of sync with the Teams app. The store allows upload of custom apps based on manifest version 1.5, but App Studio fails, displaying a message that the manifest must be <= version 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

App Studio has been updated to support manifest version 1.5.

Please retry and let us know if you continue to experience issues.